# Pop up calendar for date selection in jsp

Tags: jsp, calendar, popup

How to add a date picker (pop up calendar) for date selection in `jsp` ?

I am developing a web application. I want a calendar in jsp so that user can easily choose a date from that calendar instead of typing and validating the date.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many date pickers on the web, just google for "date picker". But since you've asked... here a good overview for developers http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/01/beautiful-datepickers-and-calendars-for.html with screenshots and links so you can compare them at a glance (that's why I like that page).

Which one of those date picker to use depends on:

1. the JavaScript frameworks: maybe one of those is already used in your application, that framework would be a favorite because the coding/integration overhead is smaller;
2. the look-and-feel: choose the one you like.

In your JSP the input fields would remain the same, but when clicking/entering a date field, the pop-up would appear.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your application architecture, you can choose one of the following approaches:

1) a server side approach (writing a 'datepicker' JSP tag) For example, the struts2 framework has a datepicker JSP tag:
http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag

2)  a client side approach (using a javascript widget to display datepicker)
There are many JS widgets out there and you can choose one depending on the complexity of the feature set you want. (jquery plugins, dojo both offer datepickers)

You may want to consider the overall application architecture when making this choice as this choice will typically have impact on all your webpages (as you discover the need to use more widgets in your UIs)

Comment: I googled it. But i didn't find a good date picker. can you please provide me link if you can.

Comment: Adesh, take a look at dojo/dijit datepicker at:
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_DateTextBox.html
You can also choose a jquery UI based datepicker such as: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
I have personally used the dojo datepicker successfully in my application. Note that when choosing a widget such as above, keep in mind the accessibility (keyboard, screenreader) etc if that is important for your application. Also, the professionally done daterpickers such as dojo, jquery ui or extjs can typically be themed as per your visual design

Comment: Can you please provide me source code. I have my deadlines near. And many things of my project left to do. I am a Final year Engg student. Please you said you have implemented such datepicker so you might be having source code for same. Please can you share it with me

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html#declarative-example

Answer (score -1):

```
 add in head javascript code
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" lnaguage="javascript">
 $(function()
  {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker(
  {
  showOn:"both",
  buttonImage:"image.jpg",
  dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
  buttonImageOnly:false,
  minDate:+0, //you do not want to show previous date.
  maxDate:+0   // you do not want to show next day.
  });
  });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <input type="text" name="calendar" id="datepicker">
 </body>
```